# How many different binary numbers can be formed using 8 bits if:

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

So the question says

How many different binary numbers can be formed using 8 bits if:
1- In each number there are 3 adjacent ones
2- In each number there are exactly 6 ones
(Edit: Each Part is different and solved separately)

I solved easily using logic but the thing is, we need to solve using permutation and combination rules
I don't have any clue about the right answers

I got 6 for the first and 28 for the 2nd

Comment: Oh, read those as two conditions of one problem.

Comment: Your answer for $1$ implies the condition is that there are no other $1$s other than the three?

Comment: What is the problem composer's intent, with respect to the first problem?  Is 1-1-1-1-0-0-0-0 a satisfying sequence?  What about 1-1-1-0-1-0-0-0?

Comment: For part $(2)$ there are $\displaystyle \binom{8}{2} = 28~$ ways of selecting two positions out of the $(8)$ for the $0$'s to be placed.  This assumes sampling without replacement, where the order of selection is deemed irrelevant.

Comment: Oh I am sorry for the misunderstanding
Each part is separated, and solved separately

Comment: Your answer to the second question is correct since there are $\binom{8}{6} = 28$ ways to select exactly six of the eight positions to be filled with ones.  Your answer for the first question would be correct if the problem asked in how many $8$-bit binary numbers are there exactly three ones if the three ones are adjacent?  However, it does not say that there  are exactly three ones, which means you missed all the cases with more than three ones.